# How to click on webpage based on coordinates?

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I need your help on clicking on a webpage.
When connecting on a website, the login page opens automatically as a popup in the middle of the page. The unique way to close the pop-up is by clicking in any place around the pop-up itself.
With python I've already tried with clickin on the html but after that the website recognize that I'm using a bot to navigate the website.
So there is a way to fake the mouse clicking on coordinates like X= 1300 Y=700 (a spot around the pop-up) using selenium or any other way?

Many thanks

Comment: Did this pop close by pressing Enter or other Key?

Comment: Nope, tried with all keys. No one works

Comment: You Can TRY:` modal = browser.switch_to.alert modal.dismiss()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `move_by_offset` method which is present in `ActionChains` class.

The internal code description is shown below:

```
def move_by_offset(self, xoffset, yoffset):
    """
    Moving the mouse to an offset from current mouse position.

    :Args:
     - xoffset: X offset to move to, as a positive or negative integer.
     - yoffset: Y offset to move to, as a positive or negative integer.
    """
```

So, your effective code would be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(1300, 700).pause(2).click().perform()
```